# Displaying replacement strategy of Level 1 Cache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cache, caching

I want to find out which replacement strategy my Level 1 Cache (8-way Set-associative) is using. Where can I find this information in Linux? Running `dmidecode -t cache` gives me all kinds of information about the cache but not this one:

```
Handle 0x0008, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Through
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 32 kB
    Maximum Size: 32 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Unknown
    Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Parity
    System Type: Data
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative
```

Comment: What is your purpose?  If you're into CPU engineering, you'll have to read a library on the processor specs and operations;  if you're into kernel development, lots of source code is waiting patiently for you to look at;  and if you're looking for FS cache, you're just looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: The sole purpose is curiosity in this case. I thought this information should be exposed by linux in some way, so I don't have to read the processor spec to obtain it.

Comment: It does not have to have control over it to display the information in one way or the other. I guess it doesn't have control over the chassis either, yet I can obtain some information about it :)

Comment: Lets say I want to hire you to do a job, I will make sure you know what you're talking about, but I won't place electrodes in your head to analyze how it operates.  It's the same thing with the operating system that uses the hardware (CPU in this case).  The kernel just needs to know how to talk to the CPU, not how it operates internally.

Comment: The only information you can get about the chassis, like temperature and fan speed, is through components that were meant to do exactly that (provide that information to the OS so it can adapt to it).

Comment: So you are saying components do only expose information that is directly usable by the kernel?! I would think they also expose some information for the sole purpose of displaying them to the user. So you are basically saying that the information is only accessible via the CPU spec or what is your point?

Comment: I'm not saying they don't expose anything.  As you can already see in your question, information is indeed provided which is not absolutely essential, but the full spec is not stored in the CPU.  `lshw -C memory` might give you complementary information but it's also quite limited.

Comment: Well linux might also maintain a database of components, so these informations would not necessary need to be coming from the components directly. All things said are basically no-brainers and do not answer the question.

Comment: I'm sorry for you, but if the information visible to the OS is apparently not sufficient for you, you will need to look at the hardware specs.  This question is therefore off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it attempts to get hardware information which is not exposed to the OS, so it can not be OS related.

Comment: It is not clear to me (nor to you I guess), that `dmidecode -t cache` does display all information about a cache available to Linux (there might be more somewhere in `\proc` or elsewhere I guess...). So it is indeed OS related.

Comment: It's up to others to decide if they agree with me or not at this point.

Comment: It seems to me that "you can't do that in Linux" is a perfectly valid answer to an on-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find this information in Linux (and you can't find it in Windows, or any other OS, either). And the BIOS doesn't know about it, so `dmidecode` won't give you this information. Nor is their any documented CPU model register where the BIOS, the OS or a user program can get this information.

The only way you can find out something about it is to read papers by Intel, where they describe ideas about replacement strategies, and the do measurements to guess what the replacement strategy of your CPU could be. [Here](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/) is an example where they did something like this.

Comment: Although your answer is right and appropriate, it does not give a solution to OP and simply justifies that the question is off-topic.  You should therefore flag it as such and place this information in a comment.